# Snap unable to download any app and shows an error

Tags: snap

[image: Image of The Process]

After waiting some time i got this error

```
$ sudo snap install spotify
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "gnome-3-38-2004" (140) from channel "stable" (unexpected EOF)
```

I have tried everything from rebooting system to reinstalling snapd.